# Seekbar thumb being enlarged on tablet

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-seekbar, xml-drawable

I have a vertical seekbar and am using a custom drawable as the thumb. On a phone, everything works properly, but on a tablet, the seekbars thumb images are enlarged. Heres some screenshots:

On phone: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Duv3E.png

tablet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSpfC.png

Heres the code for the drawable:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>

    <shape>
        <size
            android:height="30dp"
            android:width="20dp" />

        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/scroll_thumb" android:width="28dp" android:height="23dp" android:top="3dp">


</item>

</layer-list>
```

drawable/scroll_thumb is the actual image which is 400x300px or so.

I've tried a few things I thought might work, for example:

```
Drawable leftThumb = getDrawable(R.drawable.seekbar_thumb);
Drawable rightThumb = mRightSeek.getThumb();

leftThumb.setBounds(100, 100, 50, 50);
rightThumb.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);

mLeftSeek.setThumb(leftThumb);
mRightSeek.setThumb(rightThumb);
```

None of the above seems to have an effect. What is causing this enlargement, and whats the fix?

Answer (score 0):

It maybe dpi compatibility problem. You need to provide all resolutions `scroll_thumb` resources to corresponding `drawable-hdpi`,`drawable-xhdpi`,`drawable-xxhdpi` folders. Or put the highest resource to `drawable-xxhdpi` folder.